# Node/Express Uploading multiple files

Tags: node.js, express

I have the below node/express code that is taking a file posted to my endpoint     //and storing it on the OS. I relatively new at Node and see that this code is creating two files when i post. One with the original filename and another with what appears to be a uuid. What in my code is making it create two files instead of just posting the one?

```
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')
const shell = require('shelljs')
const app = require('express')

const upload = multer({ dest: './upload' });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {

  const tmp_path = req.file.path;

  const target_path = './upload/' + req.file.originalname;

  const src = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path);
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
  src.pipe(dest);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the multer middleware and giving it a destination directory, so it'll create a file there.  You're then creating your own WriteStream and writing it again.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are uploading twice. Once in middleware and once in the code.

For solving this problem, my suggestion is that transfer the whole process of upload to out of the route:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads/")
        // you need to create uploads folder before than running the code
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var originalname = file.originalname
        var extension = originalname.split(".")
        filename =
            // you can edit here to build any custom name
            file.originalname +
            extension[extension.length - 1]
        cb(null, filename)
    }
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage})

var avatarFileUpload = upload.single('file')
```

And then **use *avatarFileUpload* middleware in the route**.